# check if entire list index exists

Tags: c#, list, viewstate, exists

I have a .aspx program that has a list that can be edited and deleted from.  I need to find a way to check if the list index exists so that I can populate my panels accordingly.  I am NOT looking for a specific element within the list.  Just something as simple as does list[2] exist for example.  I would supply code for this but I cannot seem to find anything that at least gets me started.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: check it this way  `index<list.Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to find length of the list?

`your_list.count` 
will give you number of the elements, so indexes `from 0 to Count - 1` exists. 
You can also verify that `list[2] != null` to be sure.

Comment: No, I am not trying to get the length and I tried list[2] != null.  I am wondering if I should do a try/catch to get around the out of range error.

Comment: Once more, if your object in 0 to Count-1 range, you should not. Actually, inside, List holds items "array", and Count just specify there size. Only reason you can - if you are modifying your list in the same time (remove items).

Comment: Thank you so much, it took me awhile unfortunately however I finally got it.  Thanks again.